# rake aborted! undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass for capstone ptourist app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error every time I run 'heroku run rake ptourist:reset_all --remote staging' command.
 Please let me know if more information is needed in order to adequately answer the question.
**Full trace:**

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.4.1/lib/mongo/cluster.rb:167:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.4.1/lib/mongo/client.rb:370:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.4.1/lib/mongo/client.rb:370:in `create_from_addresses'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.4.1/lib/mongo/client.rb:235:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.2.0/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:64:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.2.0/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:64:in `create_client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.2.0/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:42:in `default'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.2.0/lib/mongoid/clients.rb:38:in `default'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/mongo2/truncation_mixin.rb:18:in `database'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/mongo2/truncation_mixin.rb:29:in `collections'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/mongo2/truncation_mixin.rb:9:in `clean'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:46:in `clean_with'
/app/lib/tasks/ptourist.rake:101:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ptourist:reset_all => ptourist:users => ptourist:delete_all => ptourist:delete_subjects
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when foreign key values in your table contains empty data. The only way to solve this error is by deleting all the tables in which foreign key is present or make the entry in that table manually from console.

For example, employee table contains a column `employee_type` as a reference and that data is nil. Then we may get this error.